# Random redirects to homepage/index.php

Tags: backend, redirect, frontend

Today I found a weird error with our Magento installation. Before the weekend but today I am getting weird random redirects to homepage/index.php. I first noticed it when using the Backend, when clicking something I was redirected to homepage/index.php.

After this I began investigating. I noticed that it also happend in the frontend. Completly random in my eyes I was redirect tot homepage/index.php. There aren't real specific pages on wich it happens but just random.

I could click the Magento logo in the topleft in the backend for ten times and the next click it would redirect to homepage/index.php. The second time it only took a couple of clicks, so like I said completly random.

Do you guys have a suggestion?

Comment: look through your logs (Apache/Magento) and look at your .htaccess for starter and tell us if you find anything usable.

Comment: Did you hard-code any links?  If you did, perhaps there's an issue getting the correct path/location of the destination.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. The thing is our server doesn't work with .htaccess, so in my opinion our .htaccess file can't be the problem. In the system.log I can only find errors from a month ago nothing about this.

Comment: @NotJay This thing happens random and not with a specific link. I could click on an product and it would redirect me. I could click on my Logo and it would redirect me. I can click a product ten times normal but the next time it would sent me to homepage/index.php. It seems to not be tied to a specific link or something like that.

Comment: Can you try to determine if there is any sort of pattern?  IE: the error occurs on 2nd tier or 3rd tier urls only?  Which links does the error happen with?  Just home page link?  With logo links, Magento has a code you can use for the store base url rather than just a `/`.  Perhaps that's confusing your htaccess or url rewrites.

Comment: @NotJay It seems to happen in 1nd, 2nd and 3rd tier urls. So it happens when I click my logo, Magento logo in backend, clicking on products, clicking on categories, clicking various buttons in backend. You could try to go to my website www.easytubs.nl. Just click on the logo a bunch of times and you will probaly see it.

Comment: Just now I also got a redirect to the install page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read about this yesterday.
Now with your comment about redirecting to installer seems relative:

> There is a bug in Magento will crash the shop when a specific API request is made. Only Magento 1.9.0.0 and 1.9.0.1 are affected. This was fixed earlier by Magento in patch SUPEE3762, but apparently many people have overlooked this one.

Symptoms:

The frontpage will redirect to /index.php/install
You will get errors such as:

1
2
3
PHP Warning: SoapServer::SoapServer(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity 
"http://hostname.com/index.php/api/soap/index/?wsdl=1&wsdl%2F_vti_bin%2FListData_svc%2F%24metadata=" 
in /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Soap/Server.php on line 811
A quick fix (thanks to Ben Lessani) is to put this on top of index.php:

1
libxml_disable_entity_loader(false);

[from here](https://www.byte.nl/blog/denial-of-service-flaw-in-magento)

Comment: Vvvaida Thanks for your help. This seems to have fixed my problem. I am very gratefull!

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion .
Have a look at your header html code
Especially the part where logo and link to your homepage is.
Make sure your logo+link tags to the homepage are properly closed see below

```
<a href="/"> logo img </a>
```

You can also run your page though W3C
Validator to automate your job :)

[w3c](https://validator.w3.org)

Comment: Because the error is random and not tied to a specific link I think your solution will not be the one I am looking for. It can happen with almost any of the links on my website.

Comment: I run your site though w3c validator and found those errors https://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Feasytubs.nl&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0 try to fix those and see if it helps. Especially the ones with list tag.

Comment: These things where there way before this error started to happen. Nothing has changed to the things the validator mentions so in my opinion they can't be the solution for the problem. And it wouldn't explain why my error also happens in the backend because these are all frontend issues.

Comment: Because you never know, I fixed most of the problems which the validator mentions. But with no luck still getting the redirect